Saving changed file in assembly (emu8086)
I need to replace a specific letter in a file, entered by the user from the keyboard, with my name throughout the entire file, and then save it as a new file.
The part of code, where the problem is. It always jumps to an error, but with the path, everything is alright:
write_to_new_file:
    mov ah, 3Ch
    lea dx, new_file
    mov al, 0
    int 21h
    jc file_error
    mov bx, ax

this is the whole part of the code, where I'm replacing the letter + trying to create a new file with changes:
org 100h

jmp start

; File paths
file1 db "c:\emu8086\vdrive\C\file1.txt", 0 ; and files 2 and 3 almost same paths
new_file db "c:\emu8086\vdrive\C\created_folder\file_corrected.txt", 0
handle dw ?

...

; General messages
...

; Replace functionality messages
...
start:
mov ax, cs
;mov dx, ax
mov es, ax
...
;********** REPLACEMENT ********************* 
    ; Create new file
    lea dx, new_file
    mov ah, 3Ch ; Create file function
    mov cx, 0   ; Normal attributes
    int 21h
    mov bx, ax ; Save handle of new file in BX
    
choose_file_for_replacement:
mov dx, offset replace_message ; Load address of footer
mov ah, 09h          ; DOS service to display string
int 21h              ; Call DOS interrupt

; Wait for user input
mov ah, 01h          ; DOS service to read character
int 21h              ; Call DOS interrupt
 
; Compare input directly with ASCII values for '1', '2', '3'
cmp al, '1'          ; Compare with '1'
je replace_file1
cmp al, '2'          ; Compare with '2'
je replace_file2
cmp al, '3'          ; Compare with '3'      
je replace_file3

replace_file1:
; Initialize data segment
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Open the file
    mov ah, 3Dh                ; Open file function
    mov al, 0                  ; Open for reading
    lea dx, file1              ; Load address of file name
    int 21h
    jc file_error              ; If error, jump to error handling
    mov bx, ax                 ; Store file handle in BX
    jmp read_into_buffer
    
replace_file2:
...
replace_file3:
...

read_into_buffer:
    mov ah, 3Fh                ; Read file function
    lea dx, buf                ; Load address of buffer
    mov cx, 255                ; Number of bytes to read
    int 21h
    jc file_error              ; If error, jump to error handling
    mov si, offset buf         ; SI points to the buffer

    ; Prompt user to enter the character to replace
    mov ah, 02h          ; DOS service to write character
    mov dx, offset prompt
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    ; Read the character from the user
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov bl, al ; Store user input in BL
    mov ah, 02h          ; DOS service to write character

    ; Process the buffer
process_message:
    mov al, [si]
    cmp al, 0
    je write_to_new_file
    cmp al, bl
    jne skip_replacement

    ; Replace character with name
    mov di, offset replacement
output_replacement:
    mov al, [di]
    cmp al, 0
    je continue_processing
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    inc di
    jmp output_replacement

skip_replacement:
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

continue_processing:
    inc si
    jmp process_message

write_to_new_file:
    mov ah, 3Ch
    lea dx, new_file
    mov al, 0
    int 21h
    jc file_error
    mov bx, ax

    ; Calculate the length of the modified buffer
    mov cx, si ; SI points to the end of the modified part

    ; Write the modified content to the new file
    mov ah, 40h
    lea dx, buf
    int 21h
    jc file_error

    ; Close the new file
    mov ah, 3Eh
    int 21h

    ; Display success message
    lea dx, success_message
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    jmp end_program

file_error:
    ; Display error message
    lea dx, message_error
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    jmp end_program
...


I have tried to find some info about this on the internet, but couldn't find anything similar with saving a changed copy of the existing file
ps. if some others parts of the code are needed, please, tell me

You forgot to say what your problem is. Also use your emu8086 to single step the code and see where it goes wrong.

oh, thanks! I will edit my question

From a quick glance your output_replacement is simply printing the replacement to the console and not updating the buffer so you will be writing out the unchanged data. Also your loop ends at a zero byte instead of using the length of the data read. As for style, your replace_file blocks only differ in the file name so you could remove a lot of duplicated code.

You have a comment Calculate the length of the modified buffer but you do not actually calculate the length at all.

thank you a lot, Jester! I will check it


write_to_new_file:
 mov ah, 3Ch
 lea dx, new_file
 mov al, 0
 int 21h
 jc file_error
 mov bx, ax

new_file db "c:\emu8086\vdrive\C\created_folder\file_corrected.txt", 0



The part of code, where the problem is. It always jumps to an error, but with the path, everything is alright:

DOS limits the length of filenames and directory names to 8 characters plus an optional 3-character extension. Both your "created_folder" and "file_corrected.txt" are breaking the rule.
And the DOS.CreateFile function 3Ch expects CX as an input, so not the mov al, 0 that you're using. Whether this triggers an error depends on what emu8086 does for any leftover garbage it finds in CX.

The org 100h jmp start is an indication that you are creating a .COM program. Such a program starts with all the segment registers equal to each other. You can thus remove all of the instructions that mean to change DS and ES.
If the "Compare input directly with ASCII values for '1', '2', '3'" should fail, you still need either to abort the program or redo the user input.
It is reasonable to assume that you're working with small source files (eg. limited to 255 bytes). Then it would be best to immediately close the file after having retrieved it into buf.
You want to replace every occurence of the inputted character with your name. Next is how you can do this:

Set the source pointer register SI to the start of your buf that already holds the chosen file's content.
Set the destination pointer register DI to the start of another buffer that in the end will get stored on the disk in a newly created file.
Start a loop that runs for the number of bytes that you read from the disk. DOS gave you that number in AX after a successful read operation.
For every character that is not the replace candidate, you just store unmodified, but each time you do encounter the replace candidate you store instead the characters that make up your name.

Top:
    mov  al, [si]     ; Read from 'buf' \ LODSB
    inc  si                             /
    mov  [di], al     ; Write to 'anotherbuf' \ STOSB
    inc  di                                   / 
    cmp  al, dl       ; DL is the replace candidate
    jne  .b           ; Nothing special, so continue the loop

    dec  di           ; Take back the last char written and ...
    mov  bx, offset replacement ; ... substitute by ASCIIZ string
    mov  al, [bx]     ; There would better be at least 1 true char
.a: inc  bx
    mov  [di], al     ; Write to 'anotherbuf'   \ STOSB
    inc  di                                     /
    mov  al, [bx]
    cmp  al, 0        ; For all chars except zero
    jne  .a

.b: dec  cx           ; For all chars in 'buf' \ LOOP TOP
    jnz  Top                                   /

Now is the time to create the new file and write the contents of 'anotherbuf' to it.

; Calculate the length of the modified buffer
mov cx, si ; SI points to the end of the modified part


You get the size of the new content not by just copying 'the address to the end of the modified part', but by calculating the difference between the end address and the start address:
mov  cx, di
sub  cx, anotherbuf

or shorter via LEA:
lea  cx, [di - anotherbuf]

